# Ruby on Rails - JQuery empty fields

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So here is my .haml code:

```
%h1= t('.title')
%p= t('.contact_us')

= form_tag request_contact_path, method: 'post' do
  = label_tag :name, t('.name')
  = text_field_tag :name, '', title: t('.enter_name'), size: 30

  = label_tag :email, t('.email')
  = email_field_tag :email, '', title: t('.enter_email')

  = label_tag :song, t('.song')
  = text_field_tag :song, '', title: t('.enter_song')

  = label_tag :artist, t('.artist')
  = text_field_tag :artist, '', title: t('.enter_artist')

  = label_tag :album, t('.album')
  = text_field_tag :album, '', title: t('.enter_album')

  = label_tag :reason, t('.reason')
  = text_area_tag :reason, '', title: t('.enter_reason')

  = label_tag :message, t('.message')
  = text_area_tag :message, '', title: t('.enter_message')

  = submit_tag t('.submit')

  =link_to t('Cancel'), root_path
```

I'm trying to use JQuery (and must be JQuery!) so that the submit button can't be selected (or some error throws up) if at least the email field is empty, is there a possible way to acheive this? I will very much appericate any help or tips

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `jquery-validation-rails` gem [check it out](https://github.com/danryan/jquery-validation-rails).

Or use the [jquery-validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) directly.